# Async / await as delay inside of setTimeOut()

Tags: javascript, async-await

I want to build a page that flashes in [morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code) and keeps repeating the message "SOS".

So "- - - . . . - - -"

When I try running the below code it throws an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
```

I have marked the places I want to cause a flicker with `<-- HERE` and commented out the line, so the code at least compiles.

If I cannot put a delay with `await` here then how can I create a flicker of the desired length?

```js
const BODY = document.querySelector('body');
const AMOUNT = 3;

let timeOut = 0;
let dash = 1000;
let dot = 500;
let count = 0; // fake counter for infinite loop

const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function morse() {
  if (count < 1) {
    Array(AMOUNT) // clearer way for me to loop 'AMOUNT' number of times
      .fill()
      .map(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          BODY.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
          //   await delay(n); <--- HERE
          BODY.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
          console.log('dash');

          // invoke self for infinite loop
          morse();
        }, timeOut);
        timeOut += dash;
      });

    Array(AMOUNT)
      .fill()
      .map(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          BODY.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
          //   await delay(n); <--- HERE
          BODY.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
          console.log('dot');
          morse();
        }, timeOut);
        timeOut += dot;
      });
}
```

Comment: Can you do a fiddle about this?

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing } after function body` is what I get.

Comment: What line is getting the syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set *async* to setTimeout callback:

```
setTimeout(async() => {
          BODY.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
          await delay(0);
          BODY.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
          console.log('dash');

          // invoke self for infinite loop
          morse();
        }, timeOut);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have the following:

```
const _body = document.querySelector('body');
const dash = () => _body.style.backgroundColor = 'lightblue';
const dot = () => _body.style.backgroundColor = 'lightpink';

const delay = (ms) => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

Then we can do:

```
delay(500).then(() => dash()).then(() => delay(1000).then(() => dot()))
```

...and so on... you can keep chaining them to achieve your desired result.

You can paste all that in the console and your StackOverflow background should flash blue and pink a couple times.

Cheers!